# Larvael Equivalent session all user

Tags: php, laravel

I search for this but I don't find a good answer. I need to stock a value for my website which is calculate (it take to much time to calculate it every time pepole load my page).

I don't have find any solution except to use my DB but I'm pretty sure something exist.
I want to store a value like a session but it can be access by all users.

This value is calculate by a Cron once per day.

Anybody know a better solution ? Use a table in my DB for just one value :/

I'm with Laravel 5.4

Thanks

Comment: Do you maybe mean something like an application cache, such as described here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/cache#cache-usage

Comment: @dbrumann Look like what i need, just can't find. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Laravel Cache](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/cache).

Just store the value in your cache for example calculation_{user_id}. This way you will just need to calculation once and then you can use it everywhere.

Use Remember method for that. It will remember the cache if not stored yet. else it will get value from cache and it will give you quick result.

```
$value = Cache::remember('users', $minutes, function () {
    return DB::table('users')->get();
});
```

Good Luck!